# Strange float / width issues on a custom splash page (with dynamic resizing) (

Tags: css, block, inline

I'm working on this splash page for my friend, which can be found here:

http://seekoften.com/EDMfact/

I wanted to have each social media icon be a link, with a box-shadow ease-in on hover. I have learned that since I need the anchor tags to be displayed as block to have the ease effect affect the whole social media image, but by making them display block, instead of inline, I'm now left with issues when trying to lay them out horizontally.

You'll notice that the width of the full sized images used (500px by 500px) is forcing the li's to have that width, and thus forcing everything down to the next line.

I was hoping somebody could help me get all the social icons on the same line, and resizing dynamically based on the width of the viewport.

Also, if possible, I was hoping somebody could help instruct me on how to make the heading images (EDMfact, and Ravergirls) unable to copy, drag & drop, etc. I have tried by making them a background image of that div, but it was difficult to dynamically force it to be the proper height.

Thanks in advance, I hope you guys can help me straighten this out! I have been working on this for a few hours and am at a total loss with how to regulate this, any help & advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You have a few issues you need help on. I recommend consolidating the issues in a bullet list for clarity. I also recommended setting up a jsfiddle so it's easier to work on the problems.

Answer (score 0):

This answer will be of use only to you... anyway, what you need to correct is:

```
.social ul {
    display: block;
}
.social ul li {
    display: inline;
    /* float: left; <---REMOVE */
}
.social ul li a {
    display: inline;
    /* display: block; <---REMOVE */
    /* float: left; <---REMOVE */
}
```

That will still not fix shadow, so move shadow to the img tag:

```
.social ul li a:hover img {
    box-shadow: 0 0 3px #f7f731;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! Can you elaborate on why you say the answer will be of use only to me ? Are you suggesting that some of my markup is incorrect / redundant? 

Also, I have tried making your suggested changes, and it doesn't really fix the described behavior. The li's still take the width of the full sized images, and they display vertically, and not horizontally next to eachother...

Have you any other advice / things I can try ?

Thanks.

Comment: I've changed stuff in firebug, could be I missed something. The question looks like debugging, it has no specific problem contained. Answer updated. For some reason, when anchor is `inline-block`, it takes half of width... could be that width was set somewhere in css, but cannot find it.

Comment: AHA! That did it! Thank you for that. I'm still not 100% sure why it's behaving like this, but it appears that the trick was just to have the box shadow on the img tag instead, as the anchor tag is active on the img regardless of if it's block or inline. 

Thanks again.

Comment: You are welcome, just push the box shadow to the image... cheers.

Answer (score 0):

First, you should not be using images 500px x 500px to show them as 32px x 32px (or similar size) ... this will generate bandwidth for the visitors and cause performance issues.

on the 4 images you have set: width="10%"
please replace this with: style="width:32px"

and then in file: style.css , around line 110
you will have:
display: block;
change it to:
display: inline;

Comment: Images weight is 6kb, no need to use smaller images - these will look good on retina display.

Comment: Thanks for the response! much appreciate the quick & informative reply. I should mention I only used larger images because I wanted them to be able to scale up & down and still remain high res. But perhaps I should have done about 100px X 100px.

The reason I have width="10%" on the images is because this will resize them with the viewport. If I set it at 32px, it will not have this behavior, correct?

Also, I made the changes you suggested and it didn't change anything. I'm still having the exact same issues.